# Map WebApi directly to the website and not use IIS Application

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, iis-7

I have lot of webapis which are developed and deployed independently.

Each API would have routing for ex:

`api/FirstApi`

`api/SecondApi`

These will be deployed under `www.myapis.com/`.

If I create application for each of the api(s) in IIS, I would access the api as follows

`www.myapis.com/FirstApiApp/api/FirstApi`

but I want to access it as.

EX: `www.myapis.com/api/FirstApi`

Or: `www.myapis.com/api/SecondApi`

I want to remove the application `FirstApiApp` OR `SecondApiApp` from the url.

Is it possible to configure this pattern in IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have the following structure:

- c:\inetpub\wwwroot\api\FirstApi
- c:\inetpub\wwwroot\api\SecondApi

And then have a website in IIS mapped to `c:\inetpub\wwwroot` and inside the `api` folder you have the 2 applications configured like this:

[image]

This assumes that you should drop the `api/FirstApi` routing from your Web APIs and map them to `/` directly because the first part will be provided by IIS. If you don't do this the request will become `www.myapis.com/api/FirstApi/api/FirstApi` which is not the goal here.

This being said, personally I would recommend you against doing this. A better approach would be to have a reverse proxy such as nginx or HAProxy in front which will route requests to `/api/FirstApi` to for example `backend_node:8080` and requests to `/api/SecondApi` to `backend_node:8181`. This would allow you to deploy your Web APIs in two separate website in IIS listening on two different ports and keep the routing job to the application layer and not the infrastructure.

Comment: Excellent .. Thank you @Darin Dimitrov.